# Is there anyway I can adjust the height of an LI element based on the number of lines of texts it contains? (More lines = taller LI) (No jQuery)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, height, html-lists

Alright guys, I am making a testing software. Right now, I am making a question page that displays answer choices.

I am displaying the answer choices as li elements. Sometimes, a couple of the questions that I ask have super long answer choices and it overflows the li element. My current solution is to make the li big enough to contain the largest answer choices, but now it looks goofy for the 2 word, 3 word answer choices.

So now, I want the height of the li element to change based on the number of lines of text of the answer option basically (instead of overflow, I want it to grow to put it in laymans terms).

Here are the relevant snippets.

```html
<ul>
  <li className={(this.state.submitted) && (answerkey[question]==='A' ) ? 'correct': (answers[question]==='a' ) && (answerkey[question] !=='A' ) && (this.state.submitted) ? 'wrong': ''}>
    <input type='radio' value='a' id='a-option' name='selector' checked={response==='a' } onChange={this.onChange} />
    <label for='a-option'>
        <div className='adjust-reading-text'>
          {answerchoices[question][0]}
        </div>
      </label>
    <div className='check'></div>
  </li>
  <li className={(this.state.submitted) && (answerkey[question]==='B' ) ? 'correct': (answers[question]==='b' ) && (answerkey[question] !=='B' ) && (this.state.submitted) ? 'wrong': ''}>
    <input type='radio' value='b' id='b-option' name='selector' checked={response==='b' } onChange={this.onChange} />
    <label for='b-option'>
      <div className='adjust-reading-text'>
        {answerchoices[question][1]}
      </div>
    </label>
    <div className='check'></div>
  </li>
  <li className={(this.state.submitted) && (answerkey[question]==='C' ) ? 'correct': (answers[question]==='c' ) && (answerkey[question] !=='C' ) && (this.state.submitted) ? 'wrong': ''}>
    <input type='radio' value='c' id='c-option' name='selector' checked={response==='c' } onChange={this.onChange} />
    <label for='c-option'>
      <div className='adjust-reading-text'>
        {answerchoices[question][2]}
      </div>
    </label>
    <div className='check'></div>
  </li>
  <li className={(this.state.submitted) && (answerkey[question]==='D' ) ? 'correct': (answers[question]==='d' ) && (answerkey[question] !=='D' ) && (this.state.submitted) ? 'wrong': ''}>
    <input type='radio' value='d' id='d-option' name='selector' checked={response==='d' } onChange={this.onChange} />
    <label for='d-option'>
      <div className='adjust-reading-text'>
        {answerchoices[question][3]}
      </div>
    </label>
    <div className='check'></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Don't worry about the react state stuff it's not relevant to the question, just know that {answerchoices[question][3]} loads the text of the answer choices.

Here is the css of the stuff that needs changed.

```css
.container-reading ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container-reading ul li{
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  width: 95%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the problem. With position relative your lis are 'growing' OK. Is there something about setting the width or height of them that isn't described in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I can give an image to be more clear.  gyazo.com/fb44e41017061e89071c031f11af6d68 I want the answer options c and d to be taller since they have more lines basically

Comment: Your image isn't what I get when I run your code - what is limiting the height of the lis? There doesn't seem to be anything in your code as seen here that does that. Best to put a working snippet up in your question so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wasn't really sure what code segments to show and not show cause it's a fairly large project. I ended up fixing my problem by using inline styling and vanilla JS in my index.js file. Curious to see if there is a way to do it with raw css though.

Comment: @zenith98 
Well I am not 100% sure what you're looking for, I did see your image showing your current layout so I have a little bit of an idea. I know you don't like the way the multiple lines are flowing in your LI elements so I was thinking of a hidden element that can clone your line of text and then compare its client width to that of your LI element, if it is larger, we know we have overflow. Then create an element that has a predefined flex display wrapping the text in a span tag for a bit more control of styling the overflown content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought perhaps a hidden element that acts as a *clone* as it is tough determining the length of text in an element in JS, so we just place the *list items* text in an element that grows with the amount of text that is present. This will allow us to get the width of the container and give us an accurate length in pixels that the text is taking up. We compare that to the *clientWidth* of your list items and find which elements are overflowing.

I thought it might be easier to style a flexbox elements children, so I wrapped the text in a span tag and placed it after the radio input. Then we add some styling to the selector and add the selector to the parent element. Place an `align-items: center` to *vertically* center the input and text.

```js
const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.container-reading li')

function contOverflown(element) {
  let clone = document.createElement('DIV')
  let output = false
  clone.textContent = element.textContent
  clone.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  clone.style.padding = 0;
  clone.style.border = 'none';
  clone.style.position = 'absolute'
  document.body.append(clone)  
  element.clientWidth < clone.clientWidth ?
    output = true :
    null
  return output;
}

function resetLayoutForOverFlown(elements) {
  elements.forEach(answer => {
    if (contOverflown(answer) !== false) {
      let span = document.createElement('SPAN')
      span.style.width = '90%'
      span.textContent = answer.textContent
      let npt = answer.children[0]
      answer.textContent = ''
      answer.append(npt, span)
      answer.style.display = 'flex'
      answer.classList.add('overflown')
    }
  })
}

resetLayoutForOverFlown(answers)
```

```css
.container-reading ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-reading ul li {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.container-reading ul li input {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.overflown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;  
}

.overflown span {  
  margin-left: .3em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 2;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2em);
}
```

```html
<div class='container-reading'>
  <ul>
    <li class="answer-item">
      <input type="radio" name="check"> This answer is a far too long for our list items content. We will wrap its text in a span tag and flex the input and span for a more cohesive layout
    </li>
    <li class="answer-item"><input type="radio" name="check"> This answer is ok</li>
    <li class="answer-item"><input type="radio" name="check"> This answer is also ok</li>
    <li class="answer-item"><input type="radio" name="check"> This answer is ok</li>
    <li class="answer-item">
      <input type="radio" name="check"> Yet another answer that is a far too long for our list items content, so JS will determine its length and write a new layout and style for its content
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @zenith98 Thats good, there is one other thing you could add. Because the hidden element is `visibility: hidden;` so it is recognizable by the DOM, it still lives in the border box of its parent element, so you could add an absolute position on it, so it does not take up any reserved space on the document. And if you feel it answered your question feel free to mark as such ;)

Comment: One other thing also, I was thinking that because I used a button, the page might want to try to snap accessibility to it when in tab mode, so I would also recommend changing it to a DIV along with the position absolute. Basically the code I updated today will reflect both of those changes so you can copy paste if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved with pure CSS. You already have a set `width`. Assuming that percentage resolves to an actual number, the text will automatically wrap when it reaches that width. However, width doesn't apply to inline elements. Use `display: inline-block` instead.

```css
.container-reading ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container-reading ul li {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* The change */
  width: 100px; /* Ensure this resolves to an actual value */
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container-reading'>
  <ul>
    <li>A really really really long piece of text that will cause the wrap to trigger
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't quite work for me. My radio buttons are now sideways. I basically want to make the LI elements taller if there are more lines of text. Here is an image to help illustrate https://gyazo.com/fb44e41017061e89071c031f11af6d68 . (This is before the changes). I want the answer options c and d to be taller since they have more lines basically.

Comment: Are you open to using vanilla JS for this?

Comment: @dalelandry sure, why not? What do you have in mind?